# A question regarding the analytic expression of an Ito integral

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Recently I'm starting to learn Ito calculus from the book, *Stochastic Process for Physicists* by Kurt Jacobs. However, I have been puzzled by the following basic statement in pp.46 and pp.47 of the book for a long time.

Suppose we have the following integral:

\begin{equation}
I = \int_0^{T} \left[\int_0^{T} f(s)dW(s) \right] g(t)dW(t) 
\end{equation}

The book states that the integral $I$ does not have an analytical expression. This is the point that confuses me a lot. In my understanding, if you write this integral as a limit of finite summations, we have:

\begin{equation}
I = \lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \sum_{j=1}^{N} f_i g_j \Delta W_i \Delta W_j
\end{equation}

Where $f_i = f(iT/N)$, $g_j = f(jT/N)$, $\Delta W_i = \Delta W(iT/N)$, $\Delta W_j = \Delta W(jT/N)$. You can separate the summation above as a product of two summations to get:

\begin{aligned}
I &= \lim_{N\to \infty} \left(\sum_{i=1}^{N} f_i \Delta W_i \right) \left(\sum_{j=1}^{N}  g_j  \Delta W_j \right) \\
&= \lim_{N\to \infty} \left(\sum_{i=1}^{N} f_i \Delta W_i \right) \lim_{N\to \infty} \left(\sum_{j=1}^{N}  g_j  \Delta W_j \right) \\
&= F(T)G(T)
\end{aligned}

Where $F(T)=\int_{0}^{T} f(t)dW(t)$ and $G(T)=\int_{0}^{T} g(s)dW(s)$. With this representation, we have expressed $I$ as the product of two random variables, $F(T)G(T)$. Since $F(T)$ and $G(T)$ are mutually dependent as they both reply on the same stochastic process $dW$, we can know $G(T)$ given $F(T)$. With that, we should be able to derive the distribution of $F(T)G(T)$.

So why is the integral $I$ claimed not to have an analytical expression? Could there be something wrong or missing in my derivation, or did I misunderstand the phrase "analytical expression"? If I misunderstood, what does it mean for an Ito integral to have "analytical expression"?  I will greatly appreciate your guidance!

Comment: Perhaps you mistook the integral $I$ for $$\int_0^{T} \left[\int_0^{\color{red}t} f(s)dW(s) \right] g(t)dW(t)$$

Comment: Hi @NN2, thanks for giving your suggestion. In the original textbook, the upper limit of the inner integral is also $T$, not $t$. Besides, I'm also not sure if the integral you listed here is analytical.

Comment: @NN2, it seems that $\int_{0}^{T} \left[ \int_{0}^{t} f(s)dW(s) \right] g(t)dW(t) + \int_{0}^{T} \left[ \int_{0}^{t} g(s)dW(s) \right] f(t)dW(t) = F(T)G(T) - \int_{0}^{T} f(t)g(t)dt$, \\but I'm really not sure if your integral is analytical. Pardon me for I'm only a beginner in these problems ,and if you know the correct answer to your integral could you please show it?

Comment: The integral I suggested does not have analytical expression (that’s why I thought perhaps you had mistaken yours for it). And if your integral is really what you wrote, then I think your deduction is correct (that is your integral has analytical expression $F(T)G(T)$).

Comment: @NN2 Thank you for the explanation!